# Increase white space between title and subtitle in scrartcl

Tags: spacing, titles, koma-script

As the title says, how do I increase the space between the title and the subtitle in the `scrartcl` document class?

Comment: a quick and dirty way would be, to use `\vspace` within the fields

Comment: another way, easier than redefining `\maketitle` would be to simply use `\begin{titlepage} .... \end{titlepage}` and define you're own `titlepage` are you using other extra `titlepage` commands?

Comment: I don't know, whether Timebandit does mean this with _"within the fields"_, but this _is_ quick and dirty: `\title{your title\\\vspace{chosen-length}}` or `\subtitle{\vspace{chosen-title}\\ your subtitle}`.

Comment: @Speravir I meant exactly that, but I was told that using `\vspace` is the first step in wrong direction `:)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update:** Thanks to egreg's suggestion, here's a shorter patch. We don't need to identify the whole block since `\vskip.5em` is the only occurrence in the command definition. `:)`

We could patch `\maketitle` and replace the original `\vskip` value (`.5em`) by our our adjustment. Here's my humble attempt with the help of the amazing `xpatch` package:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\newlength{\myspace}
\setlength{\myspace}{2em}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@maketitle}{\vskip.5em}{\vskip\myspace}{}{}
\makeatother

\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Hello world.

\end{document}
```

Note that we created a new length (`\myspace`) to  hold our new value. The output is as expected:

[image: Output]

Hope it helps. `:)`

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution, changing the whole `\maketitle` command.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@maketitle}{%
  \clearpage
  \let\footnote\thanks
  \ifx\@extratitle\@empty \else
    \noindent\@extratitle \next@tpage \if@twoside \null\next@tpage \fi
  \fi
  \setparsizes{\z@}{\z@}{\z@\@plus 1fil}\par@updaterelative
  \ifx\@titlehead\@empty \else
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
      \@titlehead
    \end{minipage}\par
  \fi
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
    \ifx\@subject\@empty \else
      {\subject@font \@subject \par}
      \vskip 1.5em
    \fi
    {\titlefont\huge \@title \par}%
    \vskip 2em % original was \vskip .5em
    {\ifx\@subtitle\@empty\else\usekomafont{subtitle}\@subtitle\par\fi}%
    \vskip 1em
    {\Large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par
    }%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\Large \@date \par}%
    \vskip \z@ \@plus 1em
    {\Large \@publishers \par}
    \ifx\@dedication\@empty \else
      \vskip 2em
      {\Large \@dedication \par}
    \fi
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 2em
}%
\makeatother
```

[image]

The part that is interesting for you, is between `\@title` and `\@subtitle` marked with the comment.

Answer (score 1):

I have another, simple trick solution.  Just put spaces within `\subtitle` command:

```
\subtitle{\vspace{1cm}Subtitle}
```

Very stupid, yes.  Because IMHO, KOMA script is awful when it comes to titles.  E.g. `\huge` after user-defined title font is pure nonsense.