# Reduce space between title and top margin in scrartcl

Tags: spacing, titles, koma-script, scrartcl

How can I reduce the space between the title and the top margin in my example document with KOMA-Script class `scrartcl` below?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\title{This is a nice title!}
\subtitle{This is an even nicer subtitle!}
\author{John Doe}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

I already tried [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29594) solution in which the [`titling`](https://ctan.org/pkg/titling) package is used, however then the `\subtitle` is not displayed anymore.

I am looking for a quick and dirty solution, like using `\vspace{-10px}` or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you want it quick and dirty simply add `\vspace{-1cm}` into the title command:

```
\title{\vspace{-1cm}This is a nice title!}
```

Change `1cm` for your needs. In the following MWe I added package `showframe` to visualize the typing area and margins.

With the following MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}

\title{\vspace{-1cm}This is a nice title!}
%\title{This is a nice title!}
\subtitle{This is an even nicer subtitle!}
\author{John Doe}


\begin{document}

\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Comment: I've actually tried this solution before, but it didn't work in my real document. I probably forgot to delete an earlier troubleshooting attempt that kept the problem going. Anyway, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** This answer is a bit hacky in the sense that it heavily rely on the [source code for `scrartcl.cls`](https://github.com/iuf/rulebook/blob/master/dependencies/koma-script/scrartcl.cls) as *it is now*, and as any change in it can render this hack void. It was inspired [by this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94114/34551).
**But**, it does not require to edit the title, which is nice.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext} % Just for the demo.
\title{This is a nice title!}
\subtitle{This is an even nicer subtitle!}
\author{John Doe}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@maketitle}{\vskip2em}{% Insert here the space you want between the top margin and the title.
    \vspace{-10em} % Example of smaller margin. 
}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@maketitle}{\vskip.5em}{% Insert here the space you want between the title and the subtitle
    \vskip5em % Example of bigger margin.
}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]