# Modify title spacing in scrartcl

Tags: spacing, titles, koma-script

Does `scrartcl` provide an option to modify the spacing of the `\maketitle` objects? For example, I would like to reduce the spacing between the title and the author, and author and date.

Comment: No, the spaces are hard-coded. If you want a different layout you should use the titlepage environment.

Comment: Can I make titlepage not put the title on a separate page? I.e., article layout, not book layout for title.

Comment: There is an alternative approach, that does not require to edit your title, shared at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/636852/34551

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can! Just abuse the command `\addtokomafont` and (if needed) put a command into the title:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\title{\vspace*{-4\baselineskip}Title of the document}
\subtitle{with a subtitle}
\author{gTcV}
\date{2019/08/06}

\addtokomafont{author}{\vspace*{2em}}
\addtokomafont{date}{\vspace*{-1em}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle{}

Text below the title.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Now, that's out of the box thinking!

Comment: Any ideas about reducing the space after the date?

Comment: @FaheemMitha Add `\vspace*{-2cm}` to the beginning of the next element, here »Text below the title.«

Comment: So, add it just before "Text below the title."?

Comment: Note: If you use the same letter code multiple times within a document (as would be the case with a form letter), the line `\addtokomafont{date}{\vspace*{-1em}}` keeps adding that space each time the letter code is run, which is probably not what you want. If there is a better approach, I would like to know of it.

Comment: One workaround if one has multiple letters is to have a counter, and just run the command once, at the first counter. I.e. `\ifnumcomp{\value{letternum}}{=}{1}{\addtokomafont{date}{\vspace*{-1.7em}}}{}` if using `\ifnumcomp` from the `etoolbox` package. This isn't the nicest solution, so I would like to learn if there are better options.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Sorry, I don't understand your issue. Ask a new question, please.